# Excluding certain cells withing a range in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a range `A1-A10000` and on every row of *column C* from `C1-C10000` I have a formula using the entire range in A but I want to exclude the single cell that is on the same row as the formula itself.

For example:

In cell `C10` the formula must ignore `A10` but use all the other cells in the range in `A`.

Is there an easy way to do this?
EDIT:
I am attempting to use Vlookup or Index|Match to make the C collumn find which row in B collumn has a cable with same number/name as the cable on the same row as the forumala is and then display the text in collumn A on that row.
This is going to be done almost 100 000 times so manualy excluding one cell on each line is not on option.
[Quick example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITqy4.png)

I have managed to get the result using if and iserror to get it to first search below it then if it doesnt find a cable with that name it searches above it. but the formula is very messy and probably very inefficient so would like to get a better solution if possible.

Comment: There is no straightforward way for that, please add more details to help you find the right solution.

Comment: It depends on _what_ exactly the formula does

Comment: As @Aganju pointed out, you will need to post the formula up so that we can determine the solutions that might work for you.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the formula.

Say column **A** contains numbers and the formula in the c-cells should calculate the average of column **A**, but should exclude the value in column **A** adjacent to the formula.

In **C1** enter:

```
=(SUM(A:A)-A1)/(COUNT(A:A)-1)
```

and copy down.

*It really depends on the formula in question.*